# Lightweight event wrapper for the terminal

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal, mouseevent

I believe this is the realm of the `ncurses` library. I'm trying to avoid having to get down and dirty with it though.

I'm looking for a program that I can configure to run a command while performing *terminal mouse reporting* translation to keypresses.

This is for use with pagers like less.

For example the MouseTerm SIMBL plugin for Terminal.app does exactly this.

But iTerm2 does not. And I want it.

I think the answer may be as simple as directly remapping the codes.

It looks like there are escape codes to switch the terminal into and out of mouse-listening mode, and mouse click escape codes actually seem to include the character coordinates. I can look at them with Ctrl+V inside of Vim because I have told vim to turn on the mouse.

It looks like this:

```
Note ^[ denotes escape (you can type escape by typing ctrl+[)

left click: ^[[M !!
right click: ^[[M"!!
middle click: ^[[M!!!
scroll up: ^[[M`!!
scroll down: ^[[Ma!!
```

So that does match up with the mouse wheel button codes being 64 more than the mouse button ones according to documentation (I like [this page](http://rtfm.etla.org/xterm/ctlseq.html#mtrack)).

Now that I'm armed with the knowledge of what codes I need to map to what I just need to find out how to get a layer that lets me filter the input.

This has apparently led me to an epiphany. I simply need a simple non-line-buffering program that listens for mouse escape codes and replaces them with key codes. Surely Perl `Term::ReadKey` will let me set raw mode and do this nearly trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

This stuff is difficult. I've been making do by configuring Tmux to handle things.