# Why does this perl program not print anything out?

Tags: perl, unix, io, terminal, stdin

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Term::ReadKey;
ReadMode 4;
END {
    ReadMode 0; # Reset tty mode before exiting
}

while (<>) {
    $key = ReadKey(0);
    $key == "\x04" and last; # Ctrl+D breaks the loop 
    print $key;
}
```

When I had it without the while loop, it was printing back what I typed in.

It doesn't even produce any output at the end (if it was buffering it or something). Like I'd run it and type a few letters and hit Ctrl+D. It prints nothing.

I'm [trying to make a program to convert mouse scroll escape codes into keypresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996891/lightweight-event-wrapper-for-the-terminal). I hope I'm not barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: String equality is tested with the `eq` operator. The `==` converts the arguments to numbers first, which will usually be zero. You would have been warned had you put `use strict; use warnings` at the top of your script.

Comment: That may be true and my perl-fu is weak indeed, but i'm nearly certain that is not the true issue. `echo "abc" | this_program` still prints nothing. However if I take the loop out and have it read and print 2 char's, `echo "abc" | this_program` will in fact print `ab`

Comment: Oh, now I see it: You read a whole line of input (incl. obligatory `\n`) with the `<>` operator. Then, you read a single keypress with `ReadKey(0)` which you may echo. The line (in `$_`) is discarded. Change your loop condition to `while(defined(my $key = ReadKey(0))){...}` and *really* `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
while (<>)
```

reads a line from `STDIN` (assuming you ran the program with no command line arguments). Once a line has been read, it enters the body of the while loop. Whatever you typed up to and including the newline is now in `$_`.

Now, you press a key, it's stored in `$key` and numerically compared to <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd>. Since neither is numeric, they both end up being zero, the loop terminates.

This is why you should turn on [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) which would have told you:

```
Argument "^D" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ./tt.pl line 15,  line 1.
Argument "c" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at ./tt.pl line 15,  line 1.
```

Of course, it would make sense to put the loop-termination condition where it belongs as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Term::ReadKey;
ReadMode 4;
END {
    ReadMode 0; # Reset tty mode before exiting
}

my $input;
{
    local $| = 1;
    while ((my $key = ReadKey(0)) ne "\x04") {
        print $key;
        $input .= $key;
    }
}

print "'$input'\n";
```

Comment: As it is, this code upon exiting will print out all input a second time, yes?

Comment: Of course ... to show what was put into `$input` ... I am assuming you want to do something with the keys the user presses, right?

Comment: yes. I'm remapping keys and stuff. I'm now trying to figure out how to deal with EOF. `echo "abc" | myprogram | hexdump -C` shows lots of \x00 going in (and it does not exit). What is the real convention for breaking out of the loop? clearly unix programs do not send a `\x04` byte to signal it, i am only receiving the byte corresponding to Ctrl+D.

Comment: I guess I should just break out on a null byte as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the while condition to:

```
while(1) {
   # ...
}
```

Comment: I think this also needs to set the autoflush `$|=1;` for the key echo to happen immediately